# How to use the terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 to connect to remote bluetooth device?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wireless, bluetooth

I would like to connect to a Bluetooth device remotely running on Bluetooth Classic, not BLE. This is easy if I can use the UI. For some reason, I would like to use the terminal to do the connection.

Scanning for neighbouring devices works as follows;

```
# hcitool scan
```

However, connecting to the remote device using the following command does not work;

```
# hcitool cc 18:57:12:47:57:97
```

Although it does not work, no error message appeared.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Try this for a temporary connection, use the address of the device '18:57:12:47:57:97'

```
sudo hidd --connect 18:57:12:47:57:97
```

Read this wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup for more information

Comment: hidd is for hid devices like mouse and keyboard. Unforunately, my remote device is a health-care device.

Comment: this also seems to work just fine for headsets too