# how to enable Bluetooth

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

How to enable Bluetooth in ubuntu (running on VM) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 to connect to remote bluetooth device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622697/how-to-use-the-terminal-on-ubuntu-14-04-to-connect-to-remote-bluetooth-device)

Comment: @JosefKlimuk This is not a duplicate of that. The question is how to get a bluetooth host inside a VM, not how to connect to a device via terminal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include specific information about what version of Ubuntu you are on, which VM environment you are using (Hyper-V, VMWare, kvm, etc…), and what host OS you are running on, so that one might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the VM (using virtualbox) to access an internal bluetooth device then it is not possible. From [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3013)

> There is no progress and there will not be any progress in medium
>   term. Bluetooth devices could work when connected via USB but we don't
>   plan to support any internal bluetooth hardware so far. It's a lot of
>   work with a questionable benefit

Otherwise if you are using a bluetooth USB then check this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/963459/673145)

if you using vmware products [this might help](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005315)